# PHP - Necesito validar textarea desde el servidor.. alguna ayuda?

Tags: web, formularios

Tengo un formulario en el cuál hay una persona que molesta ingresando a la web, ingresa al depurador, selecciona el formulario en modo de editar, edita el formulario cambiando un `input` por un `textarea` y pega un texto *en el cuál incluye cosas desagradables*.

¿Cómo evito que manipulen el formulario?

**Más información**
Perdón por no ser tan especifico. Voy a tratar de explicarles y mostrarles lo que tengo, a ver.. mientras trato de conseguir la respuesta por mi mismo. Si la encuentro la expondré aquí.. a ver que piensan. Bueno sin más palabras estos son mis códigos. "Por ahora ejemplos"

**Mis códigos del formulario** 
form.html

```
<form id="reCaptchaForm" action="/signup.php" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
<input class="contact-form-name" id="ContactForm1_contact-form-name" name="nombre" placeholder="Su nombre" size="30" type="text" value="" ondrop="return false" oncopy="return false" onpaste="return false" oncontextmenu="return false" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/[&/:*<>]/g, '')" required><br />
<input class="contact-form-email" id="ContactForm1_contact-form-email" name="email" placeholder="Su Email" size="30" type="email" value="" ondrop="return false" oncopy="return false" onpaste="return false" oncontextmenu="return false" required><br />
<textarea class="contact-form-email-message" cols="25" id="ContactForm1_contact-form-email-message" name="mensaje" placeholder="Su mensaje" rows="5" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/[&/:*<>]/g, '')" ondrop="return false" oncopy="return false" onpaste="return false" oncontextmenu="return false" draggable="false" required></textarea><br />
<b>Para qué fecha desea el tour?</b><br />
<input class="contact-form-email" type="date" name="fecha" ondrop="return false" oncopy="return false" onpaste="return false" oncontextmenu="return false" required><br />
<label for="country"><b>¿Desde dónde nos visitarás?</b></label><br />
<select id="country" name="pais" placeholder="Su Email" ondrop="return false" oncopy="return false" onpaste="return false" oncontextmenu="return false" required><br />
<option value="" disabled selected hidden>Selecciona tu país...</option>
<option value="Argentina">Argentina</option><br />
<option value="Bolivia">Bolivia</option><br />
<option value="Brasil">Brasil</option><br />
<option value="Chile">Chile</option><br />
<option value="Colombia">Colombia</option><br />
<option value="Costa Rica">Costa Rica</option><br />
<option value="Cuba">Cuba</option><br />
<option value="Ecuador">Ecuador</option><br />
<option value="El Salvador">El Salvador</option><br />
<option value="España">España</option><br />
<option value="Guatemala">Guatemala</option><br />
<option value="Honduras">Honduras</option><br />
<option value="México">México</option><br />
<option value="Nicaragua">Nicaragua</option><br />
<option value="Paraguay">Paraguay</option><br />
<option value="Panamá">Panamá</option><br />
<option value="Perú">Perú</option><br />
<option value="Puerto Rico">Puerto Rico</option><br />
<option value="República Dominicana">República Dominicana</option><br />
<option value="Uruguay">Uruguay</option><br />
<option value="Venezuela">Venezuela</option><br />
<option value="Estados Unidos">Estados Unidos</option><br />
<option value="Otro">Otro..</option><br />
</select><br />
<label class="nospam" for="nospam">¡Si ves esto, pasa de él!</label><br />
<input class="nospam" name="nospam"><br />
<div id='recaptcha' class="g-recaptcha" 
data-sitekey="6LdmtoQUAAAAAD9NYaBmZGJhy5ZqQeMbFwDCL4MS" 
data-callback="onCompleted" 
data-size="invisible"></div> 
<button class="sp-button sp-button2" id='submit'>ENVIAR MENSAJE</button> 
</form>
</div>
<script>$("#myForm").submit(function(e){console.log("validation completed."),e.preventDefault(),grecaptcha.execute()}),onCompleted=function(){console.log("captcha completed.")};</script>
```

**Mis códigos php del servidor** signup.php

```
<?php
function get_ip_address() {
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
$ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
} else {
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
} else {
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}}
return $ip;
}
function check_input($data)
 {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
 }
 if ($_POST['nospam'] != ""){
 // Es un SPAMbot
 exit("Imposible enviar la solicitud, cierre la ventana.");
} else {
 // Es un usuario real, proceder a enviar el formulario.
}

 $destino = "info@guiamoscow.com";
 $nombre = check_input($_POST['nombre']);
 $email = check_input($_POST['email']);
 $fecha = check_input($_POST['fecha']);
 $pais = check_input($_POST['pais']);
 $mensaje = check_input($_POST['mensaje']);
 $ip   = ' '.get_ip_address();
 $cont = "Enviado desde:\n https://www.tour-moscu.tours/p/contacto.html";
 $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset = UTF-8 \n";
 $contenido = "CONSULTA de formulario de contacto
 IP:" . $ip . "\n

 Su nombre:\n " . $nombre . "\n
 Su email:\n " . $email . "\n
 Para qué fecha:\n " . $fecha . "\n
 Desde donde nos escribes:\n " . $pais . "\n
 Mensaje del turista:\n " . $mensaje;

 mail($destino,"Consulta", $contenido, $cont);
 header("Location:https://www.tour-moscu.tours/p/muchas-gracias.html");

//only run when form is submitted
if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
    $secretKey = '6LdmtoQUAAAAAGTxNKpBWMv3IFNqWZm_wdIKdp-0';
    $response = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];     
    $remoteIp = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];


    $reCaptchaValidationUrl = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secretKey&response=$response&remoteip=$remoteIp");
    $result = json_decode($reCaptchaValidationUrl, TRUE);

    //get response along side with all results
    print_r($resul);

    if($result['success'] == 1) {
        //True - What happens when user is verified
        $userMessage = '<div>Muchas gracias por tu mensaje! en breve contactaremos contigo.</div>';
    } else {
        //False - What happens when user is not verified
        $userMessage = '<div>Fail: please try again :(</div>';
    }
}
?>
```

Necesito saber que tengo que agregar a signup.php para validar el formulario y que no lo manipulen desde el depurador. Si no es posible totalmente.. entonces necesito saber como restringir el contenido en el textarea.. por ejemplo URL, palabras mal sonantes "sex, porn, etc..", cantidad maxima de palabras..
Gracias por el tiempo y la ayuda!

**AGREGADO**

Necesito validar el textarea desde el servidor.
Que no se pueda ingresar URL ni caracteres especiales.
Alguna ayuda? Gracias de ante mano y gracias por las respuestas hasta el momento!

Comment: Miguel bienvenido, para que tu pregunta sea bienvenida en la comunidad te recomiendo mirar [ask] para mejorar tu pregunta, sobre tu asunto te convendría bien validar el formulario del lado del servidor para evitar esos problemas, restrigiendo el largo de texto, como tambien caracteres no deseados entre otros. Saludos.

Comment: donde tienes el codigo con el que podamos ayudar?

Comment: a mí me enteresa saer que has hecho del lado del servidor para evitar estos problemas, pues las soluciones del lado cliente solamente lo harán más difícil, pero siempre puede grabar la petición HTTP y enviarla sin procuparse por alterar el formulario

Comment: por favor tomate el tiempo de leer [ask] y añade detalles relevantes como por ejemplo que tecnologías del lado del backend usas

Comment: Y de todas maneras la pregunta, ahora que la actualiza parece ser: "¿cómo evito el spam de formularios web?" herramientas como Akismet y Contact Form pueden ayudarlo mejor. https://contactform7.com/spam-filtering-with-akismet/

Comment: esto que haces @Miguel Gonzalez no es válido, si ya obtuviste respuesta entonces publicala aquí y si no justo debajo de tu pregunta hay una opción que dice eliminar para que tu mismo borres tu pregunta

Answer (score 2):

## No puedes evitar la manipulación de formularios

Si usas cosas como POSTMAN notarás que incluso puedes reemplazar totalmente tu formulario por otras cosas. Esa es la manera correcta de funcionar de la web.

Existen herramientas de desarrollo, capturadores/canceladores de javasscript o incluso el simple `curl` puede cargar cualquier basura que un usuario malicioso desee.

Intenta mejor validar la longitud aceptada, o poner filtros de palabras en el servidor que recibe los datos al hacer POST.

## Actualización

Ahora que mejoraste la pregunta veo que tienes [El Problema XY](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3360/qu%C3%A9-es-el-problema-xy), tu problema es validar datos y *crees* que se hace del lado del cliente, entonces preguntas cómo solucionarlo en el cliente, pero es un error. La realidad es que la validación de datos se hace del lado del servidor. Cambia tu pregunta para poder responderla adecuadamente y todas las soluciones basura que te han dado tendrán sentido cuando lo solicites en PHP.

### En fin la solución es:

1. Trunca el valor recibido a NN caracteres y,
2. Toma el valor de entrada y crea un filtro de palabras.
3. Si la respuesta no pasa puedes:

   - Retornar un error 403 Forbidden ó
   - Aceptar pero guardar ya filtrado

Comment: esto es mas un comentario extendido que una respuesta, recuerda no es solo mencionar el que, sino también el como

Comment: La respuesta está marcada en negrita. NO se puede evitar la manipulación.

Comment: si pero lee [answer] si no es posible, le propones algo mas pero solo lo estas dejando como un comentario; debes ser claro no solo diciendo que haga sino que debes indicar el como

Comment: La respuesta es que lo haga en el servidor y la manera de hacerlo ya está especificada. Lo demás ya dependerá qué cosa use: node, php, python, perl, asp, c++, java, hay cientos de posibilidades.

Comment: entonces antes de darle una respuesta, deberías indicarle al OP en la zona de comentarios que aclare que tecnologías usa; para no estar adivinando

Comment: No, porque en ese caso provocaría que la pregunta fuera otra: "¿Cómo filtro blabla en el lenguaje blabla?" La respuesta que di es precisa: no se puede. Y la alternativa es: fíltralo en tu backend (cualquiera que sea). Si no sabe hacerlo, que haga otra pregunta relacionada a eso.

Answer (score 1):

no te sirve bloqueando el click derecho?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.oncontextmenu = function(){return false;}
    </script>
```

Comment: con la tecla f12 de todos modos se puede abrir las herramientas de desarrollador

Comment: Los bancos suelen hacer eso creyendo que es seguro, pero existen infinidad de formas simples para brincárselo.

Answer (score -2):

Podrías hacer un override del evento submit del formulario con javascript, validar que los campos sean los que deberían de ser y luego hacer el submit:

```
form.onsubmit = function(event) {
   var error = 0;
   event.preventDefault();
   var elements = document.forms[formName].elements;
   if(elements[0].tagName != "input u objeto que debería ser"){  
     error = 1;
   }
   ... //resto de validaciones
   if(error == 0){
      form.submit();
   }else{
      alert("Formulario alterado");
   }
   return false;
}
```

De igual forma no puedes evitar que el DOM sea manipulado pero si metes alguna validación en un .js min, creo que te podría apoyar a lograr lo que buscas.

Comment: Si puede manipular el HTML podrá manipular el javascript y con modificar el condicional ya tragaría cualquier valor.

Comment: No se puede evitar la manipulación en el caso general. Toda solución real debe estar del lado del servidor.

Comment: Fly, en ningún momento puse que no se pudiera manipular. Ariel M. claro!, la validación sería mejor del lado del servidor